# FileSystemWatcher handling moving file - another solution

Tags: file, move, filesystemwatcher

Hi

I was trying to use FileSystemWatcher to detect if some files or directories has been moved to another location. The problem was, i had to use onCreated and onDeleted events to handle this, but there are many issues using this solution

- how could i detect change if i will select more than one file and press Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, or right-click and select Copy and then Paste in the same directory?
- how could i detect, if i will select more than one directory?
- the last one, what if i simulate moving file? I could delete file and create with same name in different place.

I know i could use, Timers, process locking detection, verification which process uses file (if explorer.exe then it could be moving file), but this solution is not perfect and it's very ineffective. I was whinking about this how to solve this issue, and i have decided to implement this in low-level language. Is this possible to do this using C, or assembler? I know that every thing is possible to do using assembler, so is it possible to implement this in asm? I would like to create my own FileSystemWatcher using assembler or C but where should i looking for info how to do this?

Comment: Are you referring to C#'s `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`? As someone who's worked on a project involving filesystem monitoring I can only tell you: this is seriously hard and you should use any high-level facilities you can, not going deeper unless you're willing to spend an ungodly amount of time on it.

Comment: Thanks, i saw somewhere question probably on stackoverflow, high-level solution that uses in .NET some database that contains OS change log, but this was only available on specific systems only - Windows XP Professional with SP3 (if i am not mislead), now i am searching this thread and i can't find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File movement within the same filesystem can be detected easily using a filesystem filter driver, as the filesystem received the corresponding request from the OS. Other scenarios such as moving to the other disk or moving by copy/delete sequence are hardly traceable even with the filter driver because you would need to match between the file which have been created/written to and the file which is being deleted (possibly on the other disk).

If you plan to write some security mechanism (like a DRM), then I need to remind that the data can be altered during copying (eg. encrypted or compressed), which makes your task even harder.

Still you can look at filesystem filter drivers - should you decide to go on with detection of filesystem events, such driver is a much more reliable and powerful mechanism than FileSystemWatcher.